# Google Maps do not work on Signed APK

Tags: android, google-maps

Well, i was working on an Android project which uses Google Maps.The application works well using Eclipse(Debug) but when I released the app on the market, It showed Grey Tiles.After few searches, i got to know I had to get a release API KEY for maps using the same keystore that I use to sign the APK file.

I DID that and now the Maps appear but there seems to another problem, the functions I am using to get addresses of a particular location( by clicking on the Map) do not work in the Signed APK but they work perfectly well in Debug

How should I solve this?

Note: I am using Google Maps Android API v1

Comment: Seriously, I can't believe that one functionality working in unsigned apk and not working in signed apk.!! That's something strange.. So I suggest you try another way.. keep cool..re-create signed apk with the  code there is no error..if still error comes check the error in logcat..you might be successful to solve it yourself once you see in the logcat.. and even if you fail to solve..then copy that logcat and paste it over here in your question.

Comment: Yes i am surprised at this too, even using simple MapView.animateTo(mylocation) is very slow. It take a while for the map to move to my current location but this work quite well in debug without errors. is it due to the fact i am using Google Maps Android API v1?

Comment: Application works properly in some device like Samsung Galaxy S2, HTC chacha but doesnt load map functions in others like Galaxy s3 etc